# Error in combobox: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, combobox, informix

I keep getting this error.

I have a combobox that is filled with elements of a database, and I want it such that the selected option appears in a textbox but I get this error. It only works for the first result:
[image]

**here is the code:**

```
private void cmbx_vendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   try{
      String url = "jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.2.3:1525/cubo:INFORMIXSERVER=myserver;user=infx;password=infx";
    Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
    System.out.println("Cubo conectada combobox");
    Statement st1= con1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cartsusc WHERE vendedor = '"+this.cmbx_vend.getSelectedItem()+"'");
    rs1.next();
    this.txt_dato.setText(rs1.getString("vendedor"));

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query didn't return any row.. You should check if `rs1.next()` is true.. then only extract the value.

Comment: how? can you explain me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use :

```
if(rs1.next()){
    this.txt_dato.setText(rs1.getString("vendedor"));
}
```

---

Don't set parametters like this, this can cause syntax error or SQL Injection, instead you have to use PreparedStatement for example :

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM cartsusc WHERE vendedor = ?";
try (PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

    pstm.setString(1, this.cmbx_vend.getSelectedItem());
    ResultSet rs1 = pstm.executeQuery();
    if(rs1.next()){
       this.txt_dato.setText(rs1.getString("vendedor"));
       //this.txt_dato.setText(rs1.getString(1));//or you can get your result like this
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to close your statement and connection when you finish.

Answer (score 2):

Check `ResultSet#next()` to see if there is actually a row available.

Also, always use PreparedStatement. They aid reducing risk to SQL injection attack.

Usual idiom is:

```
try {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM cartsusc WHERE vendedor = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            ps.setString(1, this.cmbx_vend.getSelectedItem());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            try {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    this.txt_dato.setText(rs1.getString("vendedor"));
                }
            } finally {
                rs.close();
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
        }
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //handle
}
```

Starting from Java 7, you can use try-with-resources which automatically close the resources:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM cartsusc WHERE vendedor = ?";
try (
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ) {
    ps.setString(1, this.cmbx_vend.getSelectedItem());
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            this.txt_dato.setText(rs1.getString("vendedor"));
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //handle
}
```